# What is going on with the app icon

Tags: ios, iphone

Can someone please tell me what is going on with app submission and the icon i have submitted my app with a icon at 72X72 so apple sends me this email

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Spotify HD". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.

So i change the dimensions to what they are after and then when i try and validate the app with xcode i get the following error.

You app icon dimensions 76X76 dont meet the size 72X72????

What is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new icon sizes are likely in preparation for iOS 7.  Try checking the documentation for iOS 7 to determine changes for submission specific to icon sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In preparation for iOS 7, Apple has asked all developers to start submitting their new iOS 7 ready apps.  One of many changes to the new OS is new varying sizes to icons.  You should submit all the icon sizes you previously used to need to submit (in order to maintain backwards compatibility) and additionally include a 76x76 and 152x152 icon.  "Splash screen" images in iOS 7 have also changed their default size, so all those resources will need to be adjusted.  Also bear in mind that icons in iOS 7 will no longer get the automatic 'shine' treatment - so make sure your icons look good without it (and it is not recommended to add your own shine - it's against guidelines and would look out of place).

Answer (score 0):

According to the new prerelease doc for iOS 7.

You need to have new size icon added for iOS 7.
Changing to only iOS 7 size icon will not work like you have done in your case as your app is also targeting iOS 6 which requires different icon size for iPad.

You need to add both size icons for iOS 6 and iOS 7 to successfully submit.

Icon sizes specified in apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)